# Given a string to match in a file how to output the specific line(s) which doesn't occur at a specific distance from the matched string?

Tags: text-processing, search

*The title doesn't  grasp the body much. Edits are requested*.

---

I've a string `android.permission.CAMERA` to match in the output of `adb shell dumpsys package`. My goal is to list the package name of the apps which are using the permission `android.permission.CAMERA`.

Consider this example: If I do `adb shell dumpsys com.google.android.GoogleCamera` I would get:

```
Package [com.google.android.GoogleCamera] (cbd5725):
  ...
  applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{235b16ab com.google.android.GoogleCamera}
  ...
  dataDir=/data/data/com.google.android.GoogleCamera
  ...
  grantedPermissions:
  ...
  ...
  android.permission.CAMERA
  ...
```

That was a specific example which was given because I knew the package name. In the original command i.e. `adb shell dumpsys package` you would get to see the permissions *et al*, of all the apps installed.

What I want to do is find out which apps have declared the permission `android.permission.CAMERA`.

If you consider all the varied apps installed in the system then there is no fixed distance between:

- `Package [PKG_NAME] (ID):` and `android.permission.CAMERA`
- `applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{235b16ab PKG_NAME}` and `android.permission.CAMERA`
- `dataDir=/data/data/PKG_NAME` and `android.permission.CAMERA`

which means I at least cannot use `grep -Bn` on the output.

It is definitely doable but I don't know where to begin with.

Complete dump of `adb shell dumpsys package`: http://pasted.co/e0cd2d4d or https://paste.ee/p/ylpax

---

It it matters, I'm using Slackware 14.1 on Laptop and COS12 on my rooted Android device.

Comment: How are the `Package` blocks delimited? Is there a blank line between them, or ... ?

Comment: @thrig Here are the pastes: https://paste.ee/p/ylpax or http://pasted.co/e0cd2d4d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` might work. Something like:

```
awk -v RS='^Package ' '/android\.permission\.CAMERA/ {print $1}'
```

This assumes that line starting with `Package` mark the beginning of the description of a new app.

Looking at the actual contents, lines don't start with `Package`, but with `Package` - indented two spaces. So the following should work:

```
awk -v RS='\n +Package' '/android\.permission\.CAMERA/{print $1}'
```

This marks a newline followed by any amount of spaces and `Package` as the record separator, and filters out those records containing `android.permission.CAMERA`. The first field is the package name. And `Verifiers:` will be printed because the permission is listed before the package descriptions begin.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE '/Package \[([^\]]+)/ and $p=$1; /android.permission.CAMERA/ and say $p' datfile
```

So what this does is to match `Package [...]` lines (saving the package name to `$p` as the backref variable `$1` will be clobbered, a lot); if a `CAMERA` line shows up, emit the contents of `$p`. (This will fail with an uninitialized warning message if a `CAMERA` line shows up before the first package line, which a `BEGIN { $p = "dunno" }` leading sub definition would correct.) This should also be fairly easy to do in `awk`, but I don't think in `awk`.

(If the input data had be delimited by a blank line, then the `perl -00` (`perldoc perlrun`) ivocation would likely have been involved in my answer.)